# Bit.ly API: List all links for a user

Tags: api, bit.ly

Is there a way I can get all the links for a user in bit.ly trought the API?

I need to list top 10 links for a user, based on clicks, but I can't find a way in the API-Documentation.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [popular_links](https://dev.bitly.com/user_metrics.html#v3_user_popular_links) you can get their top 1000 most popular, and take the top 10 from there.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask your users to make their links public (bitly.com - settings - Make bitly.com History Public) after that you can access their links on their rss feed at `http://bitly.com/u/{username}.rss`

It's not through the API, but close enough.